# Addition on arrays of dictionary

Tags: dart

how to perform addition on arrays of dictionary same like mentioned below

```
{
  'A': [
    {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
  ],
  'B': [
    {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
  ],
  'C': [
    {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
  ]
}
```

.. so on

Comment: your question is really unclear... what is your use case?

Comment: {'A' : [{
'a' : 10,
'b': 20}],
'B' : [{
'a' : 10,
'b': 20}],
'C' : [{
'a' : 10,
'b': 20}]}  this is my data i need to add all values like all key a,b so on, thanks for your response,please help if u can

Comment: What have you tried yourself to solve the problem?

Comment: but what do you want exactly? an array with all values? the sum of all values in a variable?

Comment: this should work for you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-combine-lists-in-dart/